# Updating fails (except it does indeed update)

Tags: craft3

Updating Craft (and sometimes plugins like Commerce) through Craft 3 admin gives errors. Usually undefined, but have gotten "Backend fetch failed" most recently. Once I refresh the window, it seems to be updated. Since the prior update pseudo-failure there was a message about maintenance mode and a button to continue (which I'm assuming is a flag set somewhere from the prior update). It's a live site on shared open_basedir hosting and proc_open() disabled—which is accounted for in the general config, disabling backups when updating.

Anybody experience this and/or have a solution? All the folder permissions and so forth look correct.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're bumping into your php.ini file's `memory_limit` and/or `max_execution_time` setting.  It just happens to be towards the end of the update process where Craft is (for all practical purposes) updating, and it fails in the "cleaning up" portion of the update process.

Bump those up to something like `256M` and `120` (respectively) and see if that helps going forward.

> Since the prior update pseudo-failure there was a message about maintenance mode and a button to continue (which I'm assuming is a flag set somewhere from the prior update).

Yup, it's a flag set that never gets reset if there's a fatal PHP error (live above).  It'll go away after the next successful update.

Comment: Alas, those are not the issues—it started happening after the first couple of updates; unfortunately I can't remember the version where it started happening.

memory_limit is at 512MB and max_execution_time is at 180. As a side note, there is no php.ini access on this particular shared host.